# access real time data in google analytics via apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I access the real time data in analytics API using apps script. Is there any function like `Analytics.Data.Realtime.get()`. Can I have a full code of apps script to access the real time data in google analytics.

Comment: What kind of data of are you talking about, plus post your here code.

Comment: There is an [addon](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on) available for Google Analytics reporting in Google Sheets.

Comment: Code is like this,

Comment: `var profileId = firstProfile.getId();
  var tableId = 'ga:' + profileId;

  var optArgs = {
    'dimensions': 'rt:userType'
  
  };

  // Make a request to the API.
  var results = Analytics.Data.Rt.get(
      tableId,                    // Table id (format ga:xxxxxx).
      'rt:activeUsers',
      optArgs);`

Comment: Is there is any functoin like `Analytics.Data.Rt.get()`..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Analytics.Data.Realtime.get(tableId,'rt:activeUsers',{'dimensions':'rt:userType'});
```